# Как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Разве может он обмануть ту, кого так любит?" Или лучше "ту, которую..."? Или можно и так, и так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе местоимение **тот** (та) в главной части вместе с союзными словами придаточной части образует соотносительные пары типа *тот - кто, тот - который*. Но я бы сказала: "*Разве может он обмануть ту, **которую** так любит*".